# Use GROUP_BY with extra columns in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Let's suppose we have a simple table `users`:

```
id  | name | company |  other columns.......
----+------+---------+-------------------------
 1  | A    | A1
 2  | A    | A2
 3  | B    | B1
 4  | C    | C1
 5  | C    | C2
 6  | C    | C3
 ....
```

I want to group by name, and chose the latest value for `id` and `company`. The result I expect is three column table:

```
id  | name | company |
----+------+---------+
 2  | A    | A2
 3  | B    | B1
 6  | C    | C3
 ....
```

I am trying to use `GROUP_BY`, but don't know how to include `company` column:

```
SELECT
  max(id),
  name,
  ? # I don't know how to include company
FROM users
GROUP_BY name
```

Does anyone have better idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (name) u.*
from users u
order by name, id desc;
```

`distinct on` is a very convenient Postgres extension.  It returns the first row from a group of rows.  The "grouping" is based on the columns after `distinct on`.  The ordering is based on the `order by` clause.

There are two other common ways to address this.  One method uses window functions:

```
select u.*
from (select u.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by id desc) as seqnum
      from users u
     ) u
where seqnum = 1;
```

Or a correlated subquery:

```
select u.*
from users u
where u.id = (select max(u2.id) from users u2 where u2.name -= u.name);
```

There is even a "clever" way of doing this using `group by`.  Postgres doesn't have a "first" or "last" aggregation function.  But you can use arrays:

```
select name, max(id),
       (array_agg(company order by id desc))[1] as country
from users u
group by name;
```

Comment: Incredible answer! Thanks.